# how to import just selected maven module in a parent maven module using spring tool suite

Tags: eclipse

in eclipse, I use import > existing maven projects > then in root directory, select the folder where parent pom.xml located, it prompt a tree of project and I select only one of it. but when I press finished, all project, even the checkbox is unchecked, still imported into my workspace, why?

[image: select maven project]

[image: workspace result]

[image: Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects.]

**edit on 20230224**

add photo for right-click the project and choose _Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects.

from the photo "right-click the project and choose _Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects.", seems other folder is not imported as project yet, but the source is really already imported in eclipse workspace.....so this is normal and no method to just imported the selected (checked) source in workspace?

As mentioned in https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials, section  "Working with the IDE", "When you're working with an individual module, there's no need to import all of them (or build all of them) - *you can simply import that particular module in either Eclipse or IntelliJ.*"

Comment: What do you get via _File > Open Projects from File System..._? Have you opened other projects and do they have a different name than the project you want to open?

Comment: it has no .project file, the origin source folder is not a eclipse project, but a multi module maven project, the source is get from https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials.

it said "you can simply import that particular module in either Eclipse or IntelliJ.", but even I just check one or two module, all module sources are imported in eclipse, as in the question diagram shown.

Comment: What do you get via _File > Open Projects from File System..._ (which does not require a `.project` file)? Your screenshot show that you have imported only the root folder as project without nested projects (alternatively, you can right-click the project and choose _Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects...).